# AWS GLue Spark job: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema and the partition schema: `day`, `month`, `year`

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, parquet

Glue spark job is failing with the error message: AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema and the partition schema: `day`, `month`, `year`. And my actual parquet data file in S3 includes these partition columns as well.

Code snippet:

```py
dyf= glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = db,table_name = tbl, additional_options={"catalogPartitionPredicate":"year>=2022 and month>=10 and day>=1"},transformation_ctx="dyf")
dyfdrop = dyf.drop_fields(paths=["year", "month", "day"])
dyfdrop.toDF().printSchema()
dyfdrop.toDF().show()
```

S3:
s3://bucket/f1/f2/tbl/year=2022/month=10/day=1/

Partition column names in glue catalog: "year", "month", "day"

I am reading from Glue catalog by filtering partition column using above code.

I have also tried to drop partition columns based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394348/aws-etl-job-found-duplicate-columns-in-the-data-schema-and-the-partition-schem).

Please help me to fix this in order to read these files.

Thanks

Comment: If you try to print the schema after the first line of code, what does it show?

Comment: Thanks I tried this and I am getting the same duplicate column error

Comment: how about using `spark.read` on S3 paths instead of dynamicframe read from catalog?